# Drawing programmatically oval shape with border (corner radius) on Android

Tags: android, android-drawable, shapedrawable

I`m trying to draw custom ShapeDrawable with OvalShape, filled with white and with grey border. I created a drawable like this:

```
ShapeDrawable drawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
drawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.GRAY);
drawable.getPaint().setStyle(Style.STROKE);
drawable.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(getPixels(5));
drawable.getPaint().setAntiAlias(true);
```

But the result of that was: [corners problem](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/825/device20130306143953.png/)

[image]

The idea is  programmatically to create a shape like this but with different colors:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="oval">
<corners android:radius="10dip"/>
<stroke android:color="#FF0000" android:width="5dip"/>
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
</shape>
```

How can can be fix this?

Comment: Are you saying that the problem is the clipping of the border shown in that linked image?

Comment: Yes! There is no problem if stroke width is 0 (hairline) but not a solution for me. The method getPixels() return pixels for given dip by the way... but i think isn`t the problem.

Comment: I think the problem is the size of your drawable.  You need to decrease the size enough to fit the width of the border.

Comment: By the way the documentation says that borders apply only to rectangles, not ovals.

Comment: Then is there a simply way to create a border to oval, and when stroke width is 0 there`s border but super-mega tiny...

Comment: Can see this for perfect solution of clip
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693721/oval-shape-clipped-when-created-programmatically?rq=1

Comment: Just add padding using drawable.setPadding(4,4,4,4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a new solution:

```
 RoundedBitmapDrawable RBD = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(mContext.getResources(),YourBitmap);
            RBD.setCornerRadius(20);
            RBD.setAntiAlias(true);

            wholeRel.setBackground(RBD);
```

Answer (score 47):

I found a way to get around creating of new drawables!

A defined a circle with border from android XML as follow:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="oval">
<corners android:radius="10dip"/>
<stroke android:color="#FF0000" android:width="5dip"/>
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
</shape>
```

Then when a want to change drawable color, i'm applying ColorFilter. For example if I want to change drawable's red color to blue i do this:

```
Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.name);
drawable.setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

If we want to use StateListDrawable for creating custom selectors from code be aware - StateListDrawable clears applied to drawables filters...  apply filter on whole selector by `selector.setColorFilter...` fix the problem.

Comment: I'm running into a problem: it's not possible to do `LinearLayout.addView(drawable, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));`

Comment: You are trying to add drawable to layout instead of view... Create a image view or image button then set drawable to the view before add it to layout and off course add the to the layout.

Comment: Do you know how I could change the background color programmatically ?

Comment: It was as easy as this : 
GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable) btn.getBackground();
bgShape.setColor(Color.BLACK);

Comment: Does this update the `stroke` color or the `solid` color?

Comment: In this case - only `stroke` color, because I set solid to transparent.