# Oval shape clipped when created programmatically

Tags: android

I've got a clipping problem.

First, I tried to display an oval shape with Xml only. I had the following code:

*res/drawable/circle.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >
    <size
        android:width="240dp"
        android:height="240dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#EEEEEE" />
</shape>
```

*res/layout/test.xml

```
....
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/circle_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
....
```

It works perfectly, and gave me this: [Screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/546/fj04.jpg/)

The problem is, for various reason, I must do the same progammatically.

I've got this code:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.circle_layout);

ShapeDrawable drawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
drawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor("#EEEEEE"));
drawable.getPaint().setStyle(Style.STROKE);
drawable.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(dpToPx(2));
drawable.getPaint().setAntiAlias(true);
drawable.setIntrinsicHeight(dpToPx(240));
drawable.setIntrinsicWidth(dpToPx(240));

ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
iv.setImageDrawable(drawable);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
iv.setLayoutParams(lp);

layout.addView(iv);
```

dpToPx function is:

```
private float scale = 0;

private float getScale() {
    if (scale == 0)
        scale  = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / 160f;
    return scale;
}

public float dpToPx(float dp) {
    return dp * getScale();
}
```

... this should gave me the same thing right? Well it gave a slightly larger circle, with top, right, bottom and left edges clipped. Here's a screenshot (same region of the screen than the previous one): [Screehshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/29/hx91.jpg/)

Someone has an idea on what and why?

Thank you.

**Edit:**

if I set the stoke width to a higher value (12dp), I've got this: [Screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/607/bgvu.jpg/)

Comment: your layoutparams are not the same

Comment: also, I think densityDpi / 160 == DisplayMetrics.density

Comment: Indeed, if I change the width to MATCH_PARENT, there's no clipping on the left/right side of the circle. But there's still clipping on top/bottom sides.

Comment: there may be some rounding/casting issue in your dpToPx transformation

Comment: No, I tried to put value in pixels, without calling the dpToPx method, doesn't change a thing. I don't think the problem is there.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found the solution on this page: http://www.betaful.com/2012/01/programmatic-shapes-in-android/

*In Android, when you draw with a stroke, it draws the center of the stroke at the boundaries of the shape you are drawing. As you can see, the stroke is getting cropped by the boundaries of the image. Luckily, you can perform transformations on a canvas. What we want to do is transform our stroke shape to be slightly smaller than the boundary – and there’s a Matrix operation for that!*

```
matrix.setRectToRect(new RectF(0, 0, canvas.getClipBounds().right, canvas.getClipBounds().bottom),
new RectF(strokeWidth/2, strokeWidth/2, canvas.getClipBounds().right - strokeWidth/2,
    canvas.getClipBounds().bottom - strokeWidth/2),
Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
```

**Edit**

... Better and easier solution find in the comment section of the link:

*As you can see in the Android docs, a shape Drawable in resources is actually mapped to a GradientDrawable, not a ShapeDrawable:*

And so, I've got the following code working perfectly:

```
GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
drawable.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
drawable.setStroke((int)dpToPx(2), Color.parseColor("#EEEEEE"));
drawable.setSize((int)dpToPx(240), (int)dpToPx(240));
```

Comment: Nice :) Worked perfectly

Comment: Great find! Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You use setIntrinsicHeight, try to set it to your Height/With - strokeWidth, so in this case set Width and Height to 238.

Comment: Thanks, now the circle is the same size than the XML version. But the clipping still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove this:

```
 drawable.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(dpToPx(2));
```

Comment: If I remove this, the stoke width is too thin, I need to have a 2dp stoke width. But yes, no clipping occurs if I remove the line. But that doesn't solve it :)

Comment: This one worked on me = iv.setPadding(dpToPx(2), dpToPx(2),dpToPx(2), dpToPx(2)); :)

Comment: Thanks invisbo, that works well, indeed. But I think that GradientDrawable is the best way to go, see my answer. Thank you anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same exact issue. This probably happens because of a bug in Android. The solution is to set the parent `View`'s padding to some value, then set it back to the desired value at some point in the future.

```
// set stroke properties programmatically
viewWithStroke.background
        .let {it as GradientDrawable}
        .setStroke(newBorderThickness,newBorderColor)

// set padding to some value now, then to the desired value later as a
// work-around for the weird android bug where strokes get clipped because
// android is not refreshing the view layouts properly
val parentOfViewWithStroke = viewWithStroke.parent.let {it as ViewGroup}
parentOfViewWithStroke.setPadding(
        newBorderPadding+1,newBorderPadding+1,
        newBorderPadding+1,newBorderPadding+1)
viewWithStroke.post()
{
    parentOfViewWithStroke.setPadding(
            newBorderPadding,newBorderPadding,
            newBorderPadding,newBorderPadding)
}
```

P.S.: I tried using `View.invalidate()` and `View.requestLayout()` but could not get it to work.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same clipping issue and this simple configuration gave me the appearance I needed without any clipping:

redring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#ff00" />
</shape>
```

usage:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/redring" />
```