# Stroke of drawable clips when size increases

Tags: java, android, drawable, gradient, stroke

I have a drawable circle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval">
    <gradient 
        android:type="radial"
        android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:endColor="#EEEEEE"
        android:gradientRadius="90"
        />
    <size android:width="50dp" android:height="50dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#999999"/>
</shape>
```

And I'm trying to change the stroke of this circle on code side, like so:

```
public void onStrokeNeedsToChange(int newStroke)
{
    GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable)mButton.getBackground();
    gradientDrawable.setStroke(newStroke, Color.RED);
}
```

However, when I change the size of the stroke it is being clipped as if the whole drawable button is inside of a square.

Does anybody know how to increase the size of the stroke without it clipping?

[image: Clipping]

Comment: can you post a picture after you set the stroke..

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I added the photo but it's GIGANTIC! O_O

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693721/oval-shape-clipped-when-created-programmatically